# Some images uploaded to Image View are rotating, some are not

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to upload pictures to fit in image view. But some images are uploading correctly where some of them are uploading with rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [ExifInterface Orientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)

You need to get the image bitmap get the orientation value and rotate image to correct degrees

```
      ExifInterface exif;

       try {

         exif = new ExifInterface(photoPath);

          } 

       catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        exif = null;

          }

        if(exif!=null){

        orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);   

        }

      //get Bitmap
      Bitmpam bitm = ..... ;//uploaded file

       if(orientation==8){
           Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
           matrix.postRotate(270);
           bitm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitm, 0, 0, bitm.getWidth(), bitm.getHeight(), matrix, true); 
                }
       if(orientation==6){
           Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
           matrix.postRotate(90);
           bitm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitm, 0, 0, bitm.getWidth(), bitm.getHeight(),matrix,true);
                }
       if(orientation==3){
           Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
           matrix.postRotate(180);
           bitm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitm, 0, 0, bitm.getWidth(), bitm.getHeight(),matrix,true);
           }
```

Hope it helps